# Update record in many to many relation by Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two classes, `Document` class and `Role` class and a `@ManyToMany` relationship between them.

I tried to get a document then i get all that roles and fill the set of the document with them.

Now when i update the set of the document (insert new roles or remove existing roles) and then update the document object by `session.update(doc)`, the Hibernate does not do any insert or delete statement into the `@ManyToMany` table, it only updates the document and the roles records.

Note: the lazy attribute is "lazy = true" in both tables.

Comment: you should provide the *Bean*s definition and the code involved, please.

Comment: I am sorry about that, my code use a lot of Generic functions to get records from database and its complicated.
but the main point is this :
I want to get a document and fill its set with current roles then update this set and when i update this document, i want to inverse this update into @ManyToMany table, how can i do that?
Is there a specific requirements i have to do in the "hbm" files ?
Is there need to fill the set's role with the document also ? because i have to keep lazy = true in the both tables.
thanks in advanced.

Comment: I know could be complicated in some projects, but a good way to debug issues is you write a small sample that generate the issue. This helps to have clean view about the real problem and event could not lead to a solution, will be suitable to provide infos when asking help. To help you we need to see the code snipped where you save the instance.

Comment: Did you check if your *doc* is attached to the session or not?

Comment: I solved the problem, it was because i don't know the different between bidirectional and unidirectional many to many relation.
I am sorry because i can't introduce the problem in the right way but its finally solved.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, even I can't help so much. Please consider to add the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i am using the bidirectional `@ManyToMany` relation (that mean the document have set of role and the role have set of document) and in this way when i create a document and adding some roles to it, even that i have to add this document to each role in the set.
when i use the unidirectional `@ManyToMany` relation(that mean just one side have a set of the other class) i just fill the document set with some roles.

this article is so helpful

https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytomany-unidirectional-bidirectional/